# How to perform click event on multiple elements-Jquery

Tags: jquery

I know there are several places where this question might have answered and i followed the same way mentioned in one of the answers, but looks like my click event is not getting triggered whatsoever.

```
$("#overview").add("a.main").click(function(){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

html:

```
<div>
    <a href= "index.php" id="overview">
</div>
<a class="main" href="#main.php">
```

is what im trying to do, but the click is not getting triggered..

if i simply do just:

```
$("#overview").click(function(){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

it works fine..im i missing anything here..any ideas please??
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a bit of relevant HTML?

Comment: What do you mean is not getting triggered? It does nothing? For both elements? Please keep in mind that if you want to do something with a click on an anchor you should preventDefault the event first. Here's a working Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYENr

Comment: You could accomplish the same thing as `$('#overview, a.main')`. It also works here: http://jsfiddle.net/puxrdw5j/1/

Comment: if the elements are created dyncamically trry event delegation

Comment: @numbers: added the html

Comment: @ArunPJohny: no elements are static

Comment: @JaredFarrish: i tried with the preventDefault(), but the click happens on for one element, eg: only for ("#overview")

Comment: Did you mean to do `#main.php`? The `#` seems kind of odd there.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the dev console? I feel like your code should work as is.

Comment: You know you haven't closed any of the anchors ?

Comment: And it seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dev28dqn/

Comment: here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/51ah2uer/    the click event is not getting any alert.. im trying to get these navigations working on click

Comment: You didn't select jQuery in the fiddle. Works: http://jsfiddle.net/51ah2uer/1/